# Looping through a list, only looping li's with a certain class?

Tags: jquery

I want to loop through a list. But I only want to loop through each li that has .image-item class.

I have this:

```
$.each($("#gallery .image-item"), function(index, li){
```

No luck so far.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li class="image-item"><i class="btn-comment icon-comment icon-2x"></i><i class="btn-youtube icon-youtube-play icon-2x"></i><i class="btn-delete icon-remove"></i></li>
    <li id="gallery-drop-zone" class="image-drop-zone" ><i class="icon-plus"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please share your html

Comment: try `$.each($("#gallery li.image-item"), function(index, li){`

Comment: You can use .each on a selector: `$("#gallery .image-item").each(function(index, li){ ... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#gallery li.image-item").each(function(i,obj){
 //your logic
});
```